# Скриншоты и авторское право в Android приложении

Tags: android, авторские-права

Какие перспективы использования скриншотов голливудских/диснеевских фильмов/м/ф с позиции авторских прав в Android приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вы хотите использовать видеоматериалы с авторским правом в своем Android приложении? Если я прав, тогда мои мысли на этот счет такие:

В *Play Market* такое приложение выкладывать определенно не стоит, потому что это будет расцениваться как пиратство. По факту, Вы выкладываете пиратские версии видеоматериалов в сеть. В *Play Market* есть отдельная категория для видеоматериалов, которые продаются за деньги. Издатели Вас не поймут, если Вы выложите, например, новый фильм, который сейчас крутят в кинотеатре :)).

Чем это грозит? — Скорее всего, блокировкой приложения и аккаунта в *Play Market*.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение.